# focusout jquery not work

Tags: javascript, jquery

i want #result will hide on send click outside #search_form. i try use focusout but it not work.

```
<div id="search_form">
    <form method="post" onsubmit="return checkForm(this.form)">
        <div class="search padding">
            <input type="text" id="searchbox" name="manga_name" class="input" value="Tìm truyện muốn đọc ..." onfocus="if (value =='Tìm truyện muốn đọc ...'){value =''}" onblur="if (value ==''){value='Tìm truyện muốn đọc ...'}" onkeyup="keyup();"/>
            <input type="submit" value=" " id="searchsubmit" class="go"/>
        </div>
    </form>     
    <div id="result"></div>
</div>

<script>
    $("#search_form").focusout(function() {
        $('#result').html('');
        $('#result').css('display', 'none');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please do below code

```
<script>
    $("#search_form").on("focusout",function() {
        $('#result').html('');
        $('#result').css('display', 'none');
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

Put your code inside

`$(document).ready(function(){//your code})`

i.e.,

```
$(function(){});
```

This might help you.

```
<script> 

    $(function(){
        $("#search_form").focusout(function() { 
            $('#result').html(''); 
            $('#result').css('display', 'none'); 
        }); 
        }); 
    </script>
```

Comment: document ready is not some magical function that automatically makes code work... in the op's code document ready is redundant because he is placing his code after the required dom has been rendered

Comment: @Esailija: but it actually works. After several unsuccessful attempts, it finally worked after putting insider document ready.

Comment: @Sangram adding document ready doesn't do anything useful in the OP's case